# Why do my data points end up in the wrong places in my graph?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, graph

So I am trying to insert a vertical line in my graph in Google Sheets, by following the solution given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026200/add-a-vertical-line-to-google-sheet-line-chart

I want the line to go from point 25;0 to point 25;0.00000085, but instead it goes from 0;0 to 2;0.00000085. It's the yellow line in the picture. Could someone help me? I'm losing my mind over this. (In the solution posted above they say that the extra x values should be added at the top of the column but when I do that the graph just gets even more fucked up.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group each series of values together rather than creating a mix of the series.

**Do this**

[image: dothis]

**Don't do this**

[image: dontdothis]

---

**Setup**

The chart and its setup should look like this:
[image: chart]